# TVirtualStringTree. How to check a node and its children with a single confirmation?

Tags: delphi, confirmation, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

I have a component of type `TVirtualStringTree`. The option `toCheckSupport` is enabled. The options related to the propagation of checkstates are also enabled, because the propagation is needed. I want to implement checking a node with a confirmation ("Are you sure you want to check... ?"). Unfortunately, if the options for propagation are enabled, the events `OnCheck` and `OnChecking` are triggered including for the child nodes. Therefore, placing the message in the event procedures make it show repeatedly. Do you have any idea how to check a node and its child nodes with a single confirmation?

I think of manual checking, i.e. the user wants to check a node in the tree (and hence all the node's descendants) and is asked for confirmation only once. Checking with confirmation is simple if the user wants to check a leaf: it is sufficient to restore the node to the previous state.

```
procedure TMyForm.VSTChecked(Sender: TBaseVirtualTree; Node: PVirtualNode);
begin
  if Node.CheckState = csCheckedNormal then
  begin
    if not VST.HasChildren[Node] then
    begin
      if MessageDlg('Are you sure you want to check?', mtConfirmation,
        mbYesNo, 0) <> mrYes then
      begin
        Node.CheckState := csUncheckedNormal;
        PropagateCheckState(VST, Node); // From Node's parent to the root 
      end;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I thought about using `OnNodeClick` in order to identify the exact node that became checked by the user, and (as in my application the significant data are in leaves) about remembering the previous check states of the leaves in order to restore them. Would it lead to a good solution?

Comment: Tree includes `tsCheckPropagation` state when propagates check states. So simply ask if that state is not included and prompt the user. But there's another (quite bigger) problem and that's if you display a message dialog from the `OnChecking` event, you'll break check state determination.

Comment: I edited my question (added an example solution for leaves)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `OnMouseDown` event to get notified about a mouse click. If it's `TMouseButton.mbLeft` call `GetHitTestInfoAt()` and check if `THitPositions.ctCheckBox`is included in `THitInfo.HitPositions`. If so, `THitInfo.HitNode`contains the corresponding node. You may then show the confirmation dialog and save the result in a member variable, that you can use in the OnChecking event to allow or disallow the change of the check state.