# TVirtualStringTree. How to identify the exact node checked by the user?

Tags: delphi, virtualtreeview, tvirtualstringtree

My question relates to the issue raised in

[TVirtualStringTree. How to check a node and its children with a single confirmation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46391466/tvirtualstringtree-how-to-check-a-node-and-its-children-with-a-single-confirmat)

If the options for propagation are enabled and the user checks an internal node, the events `OnCheck` and `OnChecking` are triggered first for its child nodes. Is there any way that the program could identify the exact node checked by the user, when event handler for `OnCheck` is being executed? I experimentally ascertained that the handler for `OnNodeClick` is triggered only after `OnCheck`.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing built in, you will need to do it yourself.

The `OnChecking` event for the clicked node seems to be the first one executed at a checkbox click. So, create a variable, say `ClickedNode:PVirtualNode` (normally nil). In the `OnChecking` event check if it is nil and if it is, set it's value to the node of the event. The last event to fire is the `OnClick` event, in which you reset the `ClickedNode` to nil. In between, in the `OnChecking` or `OnChecked` events, you know that `ClickedNode` triggered the checking sequence.